# Can I make my laptop speakers sound any less crappy?

Tags: laptop, audio, speakers

I'm not an audio-geek by any stretch, but the sound quality on my laptop speakers is pretty awful. Are there any settings I can tweak to get a better sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the volume to eliminate clipping, and you can possibly adjust the treble and bass to reduce or eliminate resonance with the other physical components, but not really much beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Most laptops have an audio-out jack. **Plug in a set of quality headsets or speakers.**

My Lenovo X301's speakers aren't too bad, but hooking it up my [Altec Lancing iM7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009VKJH4) iPod speakers' auxiliary jack sounds far superior.

For a more portable solution, I recommend the [Sennheiser PX 100 Lightweight Collapsible Headphones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000089GN3).